# Multi columns in latex

Tags: tables

I am having problems with tables in latex. Here is what I want:

```
Regressors                 Model 1                                  Model 2
                   Coefficient1  Lower1  Upper1           Coefficient2  Lower2 Upper2 
$beta_{concern_2}$        0.1903627  0.01208  0.89934           0.17054127  0.12093922 0.389928
```

and here is my latex code

```
\begin{table} [h!]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lcrl}
\hline 
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Regressors} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Model 1 }\\ \hline 
    & Coefficient & Lower limit & Upper Limit  \\
     \multicolumn{3}{r}{Model 2 }\\ 
    & Coefficient & Lower limit & Upper Limit  \\
    $\beta_{concern_2}$     & 0.19036273    &0.01208    &   0.89934  & 0.17054127 & 0.12093922 & 0.389928 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Regression Coefficients of model 1 and model 2 }
\label{beta}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

This does not work as I want. Can someone please fix this?

Thanks

Günal

Comment: You need as many columns in your table as the maximum number of columns in the largest row. Then you use `\multicolumn` to span multiple columns.  So since you have 7 columns in the last row, your `\tabular` command needs 7 columns.

Comment: @Alan, thanks for your comment. I am not sure what you meant. Can you please tell me where the mistake is?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Assuming you want your two models side by side,  you need as many columns in your table as the maximum number of columns in the largest row. Then you use `\multicolumn` to span multiple columns. So since you have 7 columns in the last row, your `\tabular` command needs 7 columns.

Here's a version of your table using the `booktabs` package, which is highly recommended for all tables:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lllllll}
\toprule 
    Regressors & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Model 1} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Model 2}\\

    & Coefficient & Lower limit & Upper Limit
    & Coefficient & Lower limit & Upper Limit  \\
    \midrule
    $\beta_{concern_2}$     & 0.19036273    &0.01208    &   0.89934  & 0.17054127 & 0.12093922 & 0.389928 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: I also need to add vertical borders. I tried \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}, but it did work for the last border from the left. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: It's generally considered very bad form to put vertical lines in tables (although sometimes they can be useful.) In this case I don't think you should use them.  If you read the introduction to the `booktabs` documentation, you'll see a good argument *against* using them, and the package is designed so that you don't use them.  If you must have them, then don't use the `booktabs` rules, use regular rules.

Comment: Source for [booktabs](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs)

Comment: I read through the booktabs documentation, but couldn't find any arguments *why* vertical lines are so bad, only sweeping statements like "Never, ever use vertical rules", "if [information] needs to be separated by a vertical line, then you should use two tables instead", "You should not use vertical rules in tables, end of story". Any source giving a convincing rational why?

Comment: @benroth As with many things in typographical practice, this is a somewhat subjective issue, but if you look at tables in almost all scientific journals they eschew vertical lines.  Bringhurst's *Elements of Typographic Style* also says to avoid what he calls "furniture" (rules, boxes, dots).  Good typography is art not science, so absolute rules like *never do X...* can be broken. So a vertical line in a table is sometimes helpful, but most times the table will look better and be more readable without it.

Comment: @Günal Bit of a late response but it came up as the first result on Google for me - Add vertical borders using \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Your text here}